# Find and Add multiple values in ArrayList

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist, indexing

I want to add programPercentTotalViewed from the given sample data where programId is same from the ArrayList for example programId= 59554.
How can I do that.

```
1- programId=59554, programPercentTotalViewed=50 
2- programId=30583, programPercentTotalViewed=15 
3- programId=59554, programPercentTotalViewed=5 
4- programId=30583, programPercentTotalViewed=5 
5- programId=59554, programPercentTotalViewed=5 
6- programId=30583, programPercentTotalViewed=5 
7- programId=59554, programPercentTotalViewed=5

    List<LiveEventsDto> eventsList = liveEvents;
        Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
        for (LiveEventsDto singleEvent : eventsList) {
            if (names.contains(singleEvent.getProgramId())) {
                System.out.println("Because same programId exists: " + singleEvent.getProgramId());
                System.out.println("ProgramPercentTotalViewed: " + singleEvent.getProgramPercentTotalViewed());

            } else {
                System.out.println("Because same programId  DOES NOT exists: " + singleEvent.getProgramId());
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the cars & names in here? can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: That was a sample code which does'nt work.

Comment: add your sample code and we will try to fix it

Comment: Why I got down voting?

Comment: take a look at my answer

Comment: your question is not enought understandable and clear, maybe down votes come there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> sums = new HashMap<>();
for (LiveEventsDto car: cars) {
    int key = car.getProgramId();
    int count = car.getProgramPercentTotalViewed();
    if (sums.containsKey(key) {
        count += sums.get(key);
    }
    sums.put(key, count);
}
```